# business intentionally hijacking search traffic of competitor

Tags: internet, trademark, texas, identity-theft, misconduct

Texas: Successful small business working on search engine optimization / link back / search elevation... I determine major provider (yellowpages) has entry for us. Lists us by old address, and clicks to 'visit website' take you directly to competitor. So we contacted yellowpages, and found the listing was made by the competitor and registered to an email address at their domain. Competitor is a nationwide corporation. A few simple searches verifies they did it to all of the business of like type and NOT yellowpages clients.

Obviously this is @#!$ business practice, but does it actually violate law (Texas or Federal / Both)?

Comment: This is a question about what the law does and does not prohibit, not a request for specific legal advice. I see no good reason to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this violates any state law. But linking from the name of one business to a competing site has been held to be trademark infringement under US Federal trademark law. Obviously this is only true if the name is protected as a trademark. Also, trademark infringement is a tort, not a crime. The damaged business would need to bring suit, or at least threaten to,  to achieve any result. Bringing such a suit would almost certainly involve hiring a lawyer with experience in that area.

Comment: I know I am a little late to respond, have not been on the site in a while, but thank you fr the input. We pretty much settled on the same, that to hire a lawyer and fight this corporation would cost more than it was worth, and even then the company (perhaps legitimately) could blame it on regional management and not *official policy*. Just the pain of the Internet and dishonesty that it breads. Your recognition of the spirit of the question however was appreciated none the less.